# capybara have_title NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

At the moment, this is a simple project - just a couple of static pages. I'm developing a generic test framework but am struggling to differentiate between the different test options. I have added Rspec, Capybara, Faker, Factory Girl, Spring, and shoulda (though I'm not using the shoulda matchers at the moment).

I have this controller test file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe StaticPagesController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #a_page" do
    before(:each) { get :a_page }

    it "returns http success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
    it "has a page title Static Site" do 
      expect(response).to have_title('Static Site') 
    end 
  end

end
```

When this runs through guard, it throws an error stack:

```
23:13:39 - INFO - Run all
23:13:39 - INFO - Running all specs
Running via Spring preloader in process 4498
Running via Spring preloader in process 4506
/home/steve/workspaces/static_site/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /home/steve/workspaces/static_site/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
.F

Failures:

  1) StaticPagesController GET #a_page has a page title Static Site
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_title('Static Site')

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
       Did you mean?  catch
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/queries/title_query.rb:18:in `resolves_for?'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/document_matchers.rb:20:in `block in assert_title'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/simple.rb:144:in `synchronize'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/document_matchers.rb:19:in `assert_title'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers.rb:105:in `matches?'
     # ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
     # /home/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.029 seconds (files took 2.54 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:33 # StaticPagesController GET #a_page has a page title Static Site
```

The first test runs OK and, without the second, I get a clean result. I've spent a lot of time going over my config and it looks OK. I have also looked at the docs and some support sites.

Can anybody help out?

Answer (score 2):

Capybara matchers need to be called against a html/xml document element (or a string that parses into a document), not against a response object.  By default Capybaras matchers are normally only available in feature and view specs (not controller) was there a particular reason you included them into controller specs?  Verifying a pages title really should lean more towards being  a view spec than controller (by default views aren't rendered in controller specs - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - that makes sense. Having read a lot around this, I think I'm inclined to only create tests for Models, Controllers (excluding the type of test I suggested in the OQ), and Features. The View tests don't seem to bring much over that so I don't think I'll bother with them. Does that sound right?

Comment: @SteveRoach Write whatever tests help you be more productive - The one advantage view tests have over features tests is they tend to be much faster, but they do start to lose their usefulness as your pages become more JS driven since they can only really check static content.  My personal belief is that the TDD thing has pushed a lot of people to over test things.

Comment: Thanks for that Tom. I think I'll lean more heavily on Feature tests over View mainly to have just one approach for everything. I hope to get very good at just the one thing. Maybe down the road I'll mix it up a bit. I'll live with the speed issue for now. I'm trying to get the testing balance right and I guess that'll come with more experience, too. In the meantime, I am trying to put a library of standard (to me) tests that would give me a good foundation for any project. Then build on that. Thanks for the feedback - it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Thomas Walpole pointed out, [Capybara is not enabled in controller specs by default](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec). One option is to change the type of the test to `feature` (`type: :feature`).
2. To make Capybara's built-in matcher `have_title` work, you need to use `visit` from Capybara's API, not `get` from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`.